# There is no language option in drupal 7 site

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

When I hit

> Administration > Configuration > Regional and language

There is no language option in drupal 7 site. Could I need to install modules? Which modules can I install?

Comment: After enabled local module it's appear language option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable Locale(Drupal core) module. Get new option on configuration page for language(`admin/config/regional/language`).

[Tutorial - Building a multi-language site](https://www.drupal.org/node/275705)

[How to Build Multilingual Drupal Sites](https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/multi-lingual-drupal/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's solved and your answer is right as like I done. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is be because you've installed Drupal with English. You can make Drupal Multi-lingual after it is installed, using the quick steps provided on [HowTo: Basic Internationalization setup](https://www.drupal.org/node/1268692).

You can also have a look at the [Multilingual guide](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/multilingual) for detailed information.